# NDEigensystem to solve differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

When trying to solve the differential equation

```
radialEqdouble[k_] = f''[u] + k*u^2*f[u] - u^4*f[u]
```

where k is a constant, I am able to produce a plot consistent with the expected double well wavefunction.

```
radialEqdouble[k_] = f''[u] + k*u^2*f[u] - u^4*f[u]
radialξdouble[k_] = 
 Simplify[radialEqdouble[k] /. f -> (ψ[ArcTan[#]] &) /. 
   u -> (Tan[ξ]), Pi/2 > ξ > -Pi/2]
{evdouble4, efdouble4} = 
  NDEigensystem[{radialξdouble[4], 
    DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, 
     True]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 1, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 80000}}];
radξdoub4[q_] = radialξdouble[4] /. ψ -> q
fdoub4[x_] = efdouble4[[1]] /. ξ -> x
efdoub4[u_] = efdouble4[[1]] /. ξ -> ArcTan[u]
```

Plotting this:

```
Plot[{radξdoub4[fdoub4] - 
   evdouble4[[1]]*fdoub4[ξ], -evdouble4[[1]]*
   fdoub4[ξ]}, {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Properly produces
[image]

But when I increase the coefficient k to any value greater than 8, as depicted here:

```
{evdouble10, efdouble10} = 
  NDEigensystem[{radialξdouble[10], 
    DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, 
     True]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 1, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 80000}}];
radξdoub10[q_] = radialξdouble[10] /. ψ -> q
fdoub10[x_] = efdouble10[[1]] /. ξ -> x
efdoub10[u_] = efdouble10[[1]] /. ξ -> ArcTan[u]
```

and then plot,

```
Plot[{radξdoub10[fdoub10] - 
   evdouble10[[1]]*fdoub10[ξ], -evdouble10[[1]]*
   fdoub10[ξ]}, {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It produces this plot:
[image]

Why is the double well wavefunction behavior lost once the coefficient becomes greater than 8? Why do the error bars blow up? I feel like it might have something to do with my "Method" options in NDEigensystem but have been unable to locate the issue. This is not the behavior I would expect out of NDEigensystem, as the left hand and right hand sides have way too large of a difference between them.

Comment: When you define the following functions using set delay it works: rad\[Xi]doub10[q_] := radial\[Xi]double[10] /. \[Psi] -> q
fdoub10[x_] := efdouble10[[1]] /. \[Xi] -> x
efdoub10[u_] := efdouble10[[1]] /. \[Xi] -> ArcTan[u] Somewhere precision is lost, however, I can not explain why the computation inside Plot is more precise than if you precompute it. Has someone an explanation?

Comment: @DanielHuber Changing to set delayed doesnt seem to work, as the efdouble10 wavefunction is still not a double well wavefunction in set delayed, its actually computed before even changing those functions to set delayed. So I really think its an issue with my use of NDEigensystem

Comment: What should it be? I get a symmetrical  function, but not the ground state though. What do you expect?

Comment: @DanielHuber I am expecting a ground state double well wavefunction, like the first image when k=4

Comment: According to the documentaton, "Eigenvalues are sorted in order of increasing absolute value."  For `k` greater than about `4.1`, the first symmetric eigenfunction has a corresponding eigenvalue that is smaller in absolute value than that of the first antisymmetric eigenfunction.  Compute the first two eigenfunctions to see what I mean.  I can write this as an answer with  a bit more detail, if that would be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey if you wouldn’t mind doing that, i’d appreciate that... not quite sure what you mean exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antisymmetric eigenfunction in the question is replaced by a symmetric eigenfunction in the question as `k` is increased due to the way that `NDEigensystem` sorts eigenvalues.

To see this, compute the first two solutions in each case, instead of just the first one.  For `k = 4`,

```
{evdouble, efdouble} = NDEigensystem[{radialξdouble[4], 
    DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, rue]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 2, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> 
    {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 80000}}]; 
evdouble
(* {1.24792, 1.71035} *)
Plot[efdouble, {ξ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

However, for `k = 8`, the  corresponding solutions are

```
{0.13202, -1.41966}
```

[image]

So, symmetric and antisymmetric solutions are computed for both values of `k`.  However, using the rule "Eigenvalues are sorted in order of increasing absolute value", `NDEigensystem` lists the antisymmetric eigenfunction first for `k = 4` and second for `k = 8`.  Solving for only one eigenfunction, as in the question, then creates the appearance that the antisymmetric eigenfunction has been replaced by the symmetric one.

**Addendum: Finding the "right" antisymmetric eigenfuntion**

If, however, we are seeking not just any antisymmetric eigenfunction but the one with no oscillations, more searching must be done.  First, use `ψ[0] == 0,` as a boundary condition to eliminate all symmetric eigenfunctions.  Then search for the eigenfunction with the smallest `Abs[ψ'[0]]` to identify the one with fewest oscillations.  This is accomplished for `k = 4` by

```
{evdouble, efdouble} = NDEigensystem[{radialξdouble[4], 
     DirichletCondition[ψ[ξ] == 0, True]}, ψ[ξ], {ξ, 0, Pi/2}, 4, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> 
     {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
     Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 80000}}];
efdouble[[Ordering[Abs[D[efdouble, ξ] /. ξ -> 0], 1]]]/Sqrt[2];
Plot[Evaluate[-Sign[D[%, ξ] /. ξ -> 0]*%], {ξ, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

which picks out the first eigenfunction provided by `NDEigensystem`, as expected.  And, for `k = 8`, the code yields

[image]

which is the fourth eigenfunction provided by `NDEigensystem`.  Larger values of `k` would require searching over even more eigenfunctions.